# jQuery, when performing AJAX loads, how to prevent the site from scroll down & staying put

Tags: jquery

I'm building a web app that loads content with $.ajax and then injects the content in a contentCol...

problem is every time this happens it scroll the browser down. Is there a global way to prevent this and just keep the scrollbar where the user was initially before calling the AJAX?

Thx

Comment: It should not scroll down, so I think you may have to add some code for us to look at. Maybe start by simplifying the content you load through Ajax to just a some basic html.

Comment: ok I think i figured out why but not how to fix it... I'm using deep linking with jQuery so my links are like /#/stuff ...I think it's the # hash causing the problems. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here's what worked... Not loving this bec it prevent the user from REFRESHing ajax content. I'd love it if you can one up me with something better and more elegant...

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    // Page Jump Prevention - Does the clicked on Hash differ from the currently loaded hash, if not return false
    if (window.location.hash.split('#')[1] == this.href.split('#')[1]) {
        //alert('Dude we already loaded this!')
        return false;
    }
});
```